# Can't reach port 9050

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, torsocks, troubleshooting, raspbian

I have a problem with tor (this version and also 0.2.7.*). After compilation, with and without installation afterwards, I can'treach port 9050. I would like to see with arm what's going on but it doesn`t work.

```
blabla@Raspb:~$ sudo -u debian-tor arm
Connection refused. Is the ControlPort enabled?
```

When I do this it won`t work either.

```
blabla@Raspb:~$ sudo -u debian-tor arm -i 127.0.0.1:9050
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TorCtl/TorCtl.py", line 645, in _loop
    isEvent, reply = self._read_reply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TorCtl/TorCtl.py", line 820, in _read_reply
    raise ProtocolError("Badly formatted reply line: unknown type %r"%tp)
ProtocolError: Badly formatted reply line: unknown type 'P'
```

But tor binds the port

```
blabla@Raspb:~$ sudo netstat -tulpan | grep "9050"
[sudo] password for torpi: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17247/tor
```

I`ve search many things but still got no solution. 
My torrc works fine. 
I have to say on the beginning tor can't bind port 80 and 443. After I did this it worked.

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/local/bin/tor
```

Is their relation compared to port 9050?
When I install tor from the repositories all worked fine.

```
SocksPort 9050 # Default: Bind to localhost:9050 for local connections.
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 443
Nickname ZeiberSchnitzel
RelayBandwidthRate 1000 KB  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)
RelayBandwidthBurst 1600 KB # But allow bursts up to 200KB/s (1600Kbps)
ContactInfo ZeiberSchnitzel <maillinglist@pboenig.de>
DirPort 80 # what port to advertise for directory connections
ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
AvoidDiskWrites 1
NumCPUs 1
```

Comment: You seem to have a firewall/SELinux issue. What are your `torrc` and `dmesg` ? Can you please post them?

Comment: I think don't think it is a firewall issue because before I compiled tor (0.2.7.*) I ran a tor (0.2.5.*) relay on the same pi. But the 0.2.5.* version was installed from the repos and worked just fine. For my torrc and dmesg look above.

Comment: @Alexey Vesnin root@Raspb:/home/torpi# /usr/local/bin/tor -f /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc Mar 16 23:07:37.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.7.6 opening log file. Mar 16 23:07:37.718 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1k and Zlib 1.2.8. Mar 16 23:07:37.721 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning Mar 16 23:07:37.723 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc". Mar 16 23:07:37.761 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 278 MB. You can overri

Comment: set RunAsDaemon to 0 and add **last line** `User debian-tor` or if it's named as different one write your user there. And run it from foreground like `/path/to/tor -f /path/to/torrc` - and send a log here, please.

Comment: Look please at the bottom of the page. I've added it to my other answer.

Comment: Another try: After I deleted the `User debian-tor` option but with the `RunAsDaemon0` option tor starts but nothing changed.

Comment: With the `User` option I must run tor as root. But I don't want to run tor as root and I don`t need to normally.

Comment: add DataDirectory /path/to/tor/data/directory : "Mar 16 22:31:02.888 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't access/create private data directory "/root/.tor"

Comment: You mean in the torrc right? 
Which directory exactly?

Comment: in torrc, create an empty dir for your tor to store it's data.. for example /usr/local/tor-data

Comment: Done. But which rights and permissions should the folder have?

Comment: 750 and owned by user and group of your tor user

Comment: Done. 

But now this shows up

`Mar 16 23:09:02.490 [warn] Fixing permissions on directory /usr/local/tor-data`

Comment: no problem - update your tor running log please

Comment: I updated my log.
I still can't reach the port with arm. :-(
`blabla@Raspb:/usr/local$ sudo -u debian-tor arm` -> 
`Connection refused. Is the ControlPort enabled?`

Comment: add `ControlPort 9051` and define an auth password for it `CookieAuthentication 1` and set it with `HashedControlPassword <passhash>`.

Comment: Checking Tor connection on port: 9051...FAIL!
can someone help me with this error..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! It's running.

@Alexey Vesnin you made my day!

The last post from you was the right guess.
I edited my `torrc` like you said:

- uncomment `ControlPort 9051`
- uncomment `CookieAuthentication 1`
- I generated the password with `tor --hash-password [YOUR PASSWORD]` and copied it
- uncomment `HashedControlPassword [YOUR copied PASSWORD]`

After all arm runs with `sudo -u debian-tor arm -i 127.0.0.1:9051` perfectly. (On first start it takes 1 minute or so until the password prompt is shown).

P.S.: But why I have to point on Port 9051 not 9050?